# Modifying a sequential keyed object with extra items

Tags: javascript

I am working with a keyed object that represents timetable data and in particular timing points for various stops hit for particular 'trips'

So currently I get a list of stop locations back and also a list of trips, as demonstrated simply like so:

```
var locations = [{id: 0, name: 'A'},{id: 1, name: 'B'},{id: 2, name: 'C'},{id: 3, name: 'D'}]
var trips = [{
    times: {
        '0': '06:00',
        '1': '06:30'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:00',
        '2': '07:30',
        '4': '08:45'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:45',
        '3': '09:00'
    }
}];
```

What I want to be able to do is, where a trip doesnt visit particular stops, to then add a new keyed item but with an empty string value using the stop id that wasnt visited as the key value.

So I want to end up with transformed objects like so:

```
var trips = [{
    times: {
        '0': '06:00',
        '1': '06:30',
        '2': '',
        '3': '',
        '4': ''
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '0': '',
        '1': '07:00',
        '2': '07:30',
        '3': ''
        '4': '08:45'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '0': '',
        '1': '07:45',
        '2': '',
        '3': '09:00',
        '4': ''
    }
}];
```

I was thinking of looping over the keys in each `times` object and comparing to the previous key to look at what the gap in key values are, so I could try and work out how many keys to insert - but using something like Object.keys(...) doesn't guarantee the order the keys are iterated over so I cant see this as helping me.

The only other approach I can think of is to convert the objects into sparse arrays and use the keys of the original objects to know what position to add array items at and then fill in the gaps of the array with the empty values I need.

Can someone offer suggestions on the best approach here please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we get all of the locations keys and add them to an array.

```
let keys = locations.map(o=> o.id);
```

With this info as a template, now we can loop our trips and validate if all the keys are in each trip object. If noy, we add them to that object.

```
trips.forEach(o=>{
  keys.forEach(k=>{
    if(!(k in o.times)){
      o.times[k]='0';
    }
  })
})
```

Hope this helps :>

```js
var locations = [{id: 0, name: 'A'},{id: 1, name: 'B'},{id: 2, name: 'C'},{id: 3, name: 'D'},{id: 5, name: 'D'}]
var trips = [{
    times: {
        '0': '06:00',
        '1': '06:30'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:00',
        '2': '07:30',
        '4': '08:45'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:45',
        '3': '09:00'
    }
}];

let keys = locations.map(o=> o.id);

trips.forEach(o=>{
  keys.forEach(k=>{
    if(!(k in o.times)){
      o.times[k]='0';
    }
  })
})

console.log(trips)
```

Comment: Note that `locations` is an array, so `Object.keys(locations)` will always just be an array of sequential integers (`[0,1,2,3,...]`). Your code works because `locations` does just use sequential integers for the `id` properties, but if the next location had an `id` of `5`, you'd have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that you can't rely on the order of the keys, but you can just use `Array.prototype.includes` to see if your trip is missing a particular location. There's probably a more clever way, but this seems to work:

```js
var locations = [{id: 0, name: 'A'},{id: 1, name: 'B'},{id: 2, name: 'C'},{id: 3, name: 'D'}]
var trips = [{
    times: {
        '0': '06:00',
        '1': '06:30'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:00',
        '2': '07:30',
        '4': '08:45'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:45',
        '3': '09:00'
    }
}];
// create an array of all the location ids
var locationIds = [];
locations.forEach(function(location){
  locationIds.push('' + location.id); // convert to string before pushing because your `times` objects' keys are strings
});

trips.forEach(function(trip) {
  // here are all the trips already defined:
  var existingTrips = Object.keys(trip.times);
  // then iterate over all locations to add the new elements where they don't exist
  locationIds.forEach(function(locationId) {
    // so if we don't have a trip, add a blank one!
    if (!existingTrips.includes(locationId)) {
      trip.times[locationId] = '';
    }
  })
});
console.log(trips);
```

Comment: Having a ``forEach`` loop with a ``.push`` inside, is the same as having a ``.map`` function.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, just try the following code, it has comments describing how it works.

```js
var locations = [{id: 0, name: 'A'},{id: 1, name: 'B'},{id: 2, name: 'C'},{id: 3, name: 'D'}];
var trips = [{
    times: {
        '0': '06:00',
        '1': '06:30'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:00',
        '2': '07:30',
        '4': '08:45'
    }
}, {
    times: {
        '1': '07:45',
        '3': '09:00'
    }
}];

// you loop through the locations
locations.forEach(location=>{
    // you loop through the trips
    trips.forEach(trip=>{
        // you check if location id is not in trip times to set trip times for that location to empty string.
        if(!(location.id in trip.times)){
          trip.times[location.id] = '';
        }
    });
});

console.log(trips);
```